# How to multiply two lists to matrices to a tensor?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have the two lists of arrays

```
splocations = [array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6]),array([7,8,9])]
eviddisp = [array([10,11,12]), array([13,14,15])]
```

which I would like to multiply with each other such that I multiply each list element (which is an array) with each other list element. Here I would get a 3x2 matrix where each element is a vector. So the matrix element [0,0] would be

```
array([10, 22, 36]) = array([1,2,3]) * array([10,11,12])
```

So this matrix would be in fact a tensor of shape 3x2x3. How can I get this tensor/matrix?

I get that I need to use `array(splocations)` and `array(eviddisp)` somehow. By I realised, I am looking for a solution with numpy's tensordot, but I don't get it right. How to I proceed?

Comment: `[splocations[i] * eviddisp[i] for i in range(2)]`?

Comment: @Divakar: That is very inefficient. I am looking for a numpy-solution.

Comment: `a[:2]*b` with `a` and `b` as `array(splocations) and array(eviddisp)` respectively?

Comment: @Divakar: This results in a matrix of 3x2, not the tensor as requested.

Comment: Then, try `a[:,None]*b`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want, taking automatic broadcasting into account:

```
from numpy import array

splocations = [array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6]),array([7,8,9])]
eviddisp = [array([10,11,12]), array([13,14,15])]

splocations = array(splocations)
viddisp = array(eviddisp)

result = splocations[:, None, :]*eviddisp

result

array([[[ 10,  22,  36],
        [ 13,  28,  45]],

       [[ 40,  55,  72],
        [ 52,  70,  90]],

       [[ 70,  88, 108],
        [ 91, 112, 135]]])
```

Comment: You might use the equivalent but more concise syntax: `splocations = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])`. Note also that you can do the same operation without the final `:` in the multiplication step (as @Divakar shows in the comment).

Comment: I was just starting from OP's code. I agree direct creation is better but perhaps he has really got a list of arrays. I also like specifying all the indexes explicitly. It makes it clear that the result is three dimensional

Comment: Sometimes I'll even write `a[:,None,:] * b[None,:,:]` to highlight the dimension pairing.